Using fluent-bit configuration error on ubuntu22.04
I am using fluent-bit on Ubuntu 22.04, but for some reason, when I run the command fluent-bit -c /home/gyz/fluent-bit/fluent-bit.conf  -v, I get an error like this?
# fluent-bit -c /home/gyz/fluent-bit/fluent-bit.conf  -v
Fluent Bit v1.5.7
* Copyright (C) 2019-2020 The Fluent Bit Authors
* Copyright (C) 2015-2018 Treasure Data
* Fluent Bit is a CNCF sub-project under the umbrella of Fluentd
* https://fluentbit.io

Error: Could not open configuration file. Aborting

#
# cat /home/gyz/fluent-bit/fluent-bit.conf
[SERVICE]
    Flush         1
    Daemon        Off
    Log_Level     info

[INPUT]
    Name          stdin
    Tag           app.logs

[OUTPUT]
    Name          file
    Match         *
    Path          /home/gyz/fluent-bit/fluent-bit-logs.log
# ls -ltr /home/gyz/fluent-bit/fluent-bit-logs.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 gyz gyz 0 12月 26 20:23 /home/gyz/fluent-bit/fluent-bit-logs.log


I'm not familiar with fluent-bit, but a generic debugging step in this sort of situation is to run the command under the control of strace to see exactly where it's failing.
